# Convert Promises to observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs

RxJS is very nice library and I want to convert below function from `Promises` to `Observables`

```
    async function userGoods(userName) {
      let user = await userReqest(userName).toPromise();
      let home = await homeReqest(user.id).toPromise();
      let dog = home ? await dogReqest(user.id).toPromise() : null;

      let financeUSD = user.savings;
      if(home) financeUSD += home.price;
      if(dog) financeUSD += dog.price;

      return { 
        USD: financeUSD, 
        EUR: await usd2eurReqest(financeUSD).toPromise() 
      };
    }
```

Blow I created boiler-plate working (Promises) snippet which allows to easily use rxjs (and can be copied to answer). Snippet below contains 4 api request simulations observables (don't change it)

```js
// Simulated API Request observables
let d = rxjs.operators.delay(100);
let userReqest = (name) => rxjs.of({id:123, name:name, savings: 10000}).pipe(d);
let homeReqest = (userId) => rxjs.of({userId, color:"black", price: 1000000}).pipe(d);
let dogReqest = (userId) => rxjs.of({userId, name:"Pig", price: 1000}).pipe(d);
let usd2eurReqest = (money) => rxjs.of( money*1.1 ).pipe(d);

// How to write below function using obserwables (without Promises) ?
async function userGoods(userName) {
  let user = await userReqest(userName).toPromise();
  let home = await homeReqest(user.id).toPromise();
  let dog = home ? await dogReqest(user.id).toPromise() : null;
  
  let financeUSD = user.savings;
  if(home) financeUSD += home.price;
  if(dog) financeUSD += dog.price;

  return { 
    USD: financeUSD, 
    EUR: await usd2eurReqest(financeUSD).toPromise() 
  };
}


// --------
// TEST
// --------

// you can change this function to support observables instead await
async function run() {
  console.log("John goods", await userGoods("John"));
}

run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When I start to convert it myself I write part of nested code but don't know how to finish it - this is what I have so far (probably I do it in wrong-ugly way)

```js
// Simulated API Request observables
let d = rxjs.operators.delay(100);
let userReqest = (name) => rxjs.of({id:123, name:name, savings: 10000}).pipe(d);
let homeReqest = (userId) => rxjs.of({userId, color:"black", price: 1000000}).pipe(d);
let dogReqest = (userId) => rxjs.of({userId, name:"Pig", price: 1000}).pipe(d);
let usd2eurReqest = (money) => rxjs.of( money*1.1 ).pipe(d);

async function userGoods(userName) {
  userReqest(userName).subscribe((user)=> {
    homeReqest(user.id).subscribe((home)=> {
       dogReqest(user.id).subscribe((dog)=> {
         console.log({dog});
         
      })
    })
  });  
  
  // I don't know what to do next here - ?
}


// --------
// TEST
// --------

// you can change this function to support observables instead await
async function run() {
  console.log("John goods", await userGoods("John"));
}

run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `switchMap` calls to map to the next Observable while keeping the value of the previous Observable accessible. You can move the code that fetches the dog and maps to the overall user finance to a separate function to reduce some nesting. Then use `swichMap` to fetch `EUR` and use a nested `map` again to emit both `{ USD, EUR }`.

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map, switchMap, delay } = rxjs.operators;

// Simulated API Request observables
const d = 100
let userReqest = (name) => of({id:123, name:name, savings: 10000}).pipe(delay(d));
let homeReqest = (userId) => of({userId, color:"black", price: 1000000}).pipe(delay(d));
let dogReqest = (userId) => of({userId, name:"Pig", price: 1000}).pipe(delay(d));
let usd2eurReqest = (money) => of( money*1.1 ).pipe(delay(d));

function userFinance(user, home) {
  return (home ? dogReqest(user.id) : of(null)).pipe(
    map(dog => user.savings + (home ? home.price : 0) + (dog ? dog.price : 0))
  );
}

function userGoods(userName) {
  return userReqest(userName).pipe(
    switchMap(user => homeReqest(user.id).pipe(
      switchMap(home => userFinance(user, home))
    )),
    switchMap(USD => usd2eurReqest(USD).pipe(
      map(EUR => ({ USD, EUR }))
    ))
  );
}
// --------
// TEST
// --------

function run() {
  userGoods("John").subscribe(
    goods => console.log("John goods", goods)
  );
}

run()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer - but it looks so complicated that I wonder: it is really worth to change promises to observables in this case?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Yes, dealing with sequential requests in rxjs and keeping the value of the previous request accessible requires nesting that doesn't always look good. I updated my answer and moved some of the complexity into an extra function to shorten the code.

Comment: Here is also some interesting comment of [rxjs author](https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-observable-interop-with-promises-and-async-await-bebb05306875)

Answer (score 0):

When want to combine multiple observables, you should do it rxjs way - ie. using `switchMap` (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap). And then you can use `Observable.toPromise()`. Subscribtion to observables is way to connect it to "outer" world (Rest of your application)

Then your code in `userGoods` will look like this (I didn't tested it, but play around with it yourself)

```
const dog = userReqest(userName).pipe(
  switchMap((user) => homeRequest(user.id).pipe(
    switchMap((home) => (home ? dogRequest(user.id) : null),
  )),
).toPromise();
```

Comment: in your code you not explain how to calculate finances and return USD and EUR value which is actually the biggest problem here for me (and you still use Promises)