# Old-style callbacks synchronisation using observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have following scenario - 4 callback functions A,B,C,D which are called form old-style like library (which use some API requests inside so execution time is unknown/random but proper order of results (by finished task time) is important for me)  - and I want to synchronise data  which they return to one obserwable result string using rxjs.

```
function getData() {

  // --- BELOW Part can be EDIT ---

  let obs = new ReplaySubject(1); // this is example you can use an type

  function A(n) { 
    let r= 'A'.repeat(n);
  }

  function B(n) {
    let r= 'B'.repeat(n);
  }

  function C(n) {
    let r= 'C'.repeat(n);
  }

  function D(n) {
    let r= 'D'.repeat(n);
    obs.next(r);
  }
  
  // --- BELOW Part can NOT be edit ---

  runLib(A,B,C,D)   
  return obs
}
```

In below snippet value of `finalResult` is `DDDDD` which is wrong. Proper value of `finalResult` string should be `AADDDDDCCCCBBB`.

```js
// SET-UP - NOT EDIT Below code
const { of, Observable, ReplaySubject } = rxjs;
const { map, switchMap, delay } = rxjs.operators; // example

// simulated lib functions
function libA(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(2), 1000); } 
function libB(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(3), 3000); }
function libC(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(4), 2000); }
function libD(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(5), 1500); }

function runLib(cA,cB,cC,cD) {
    libA( cA ); libB( cB ); libC( cC ); libD( cD );
}

getData().subscribe(finalResult => {
  console.log(finalResult) // The result is WRONG here!
}, e=>{}, _=> console.log('finished - unsubscribed'));


function getData() {

  // --- BELOW Part can be EDIT ---

  let obs = new ReplaySubject(1); // this is example, you can use diffrend observale kind

  function A(n) { 
    let r= 'A'.repeat(n);
  }

  function B(n) {
    let r= 'B'.repeat(n);
  }

  function C(n) {
    let r= 'C'.repeat(n);
  }

  function D(n) {
    let r= 'D'.repeat(n);
    obs.next(r);
  }
  
  // --- BELOW Part can NOT be edit ---

  runLib(A,B,C,D)   
  return obs
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In snippet I mark code inside `getData()` which can be edit in solution (may be it looks little awkward but this is exactly what I need) (you can also find there `finalResult` but not edit that part of code). It is possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do in such case is to wrap the library functions to return `Observable` and then use `forkJoin` to wait for all the results.

I took your code and modified it to get the desired result, you would need to:

1. in each callback emit the result to a subject.
2. return an `Observable` which wait for `n` emission - in this case 4
3. map the emissions into a single string

The final `getData` function will look like this:

```js
function getData() {
  // --- BELOW Part can be EDIT ---
  const result$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
  const obs = result$.asObservable().pipe(
    bufferCount(4), // or any desired number of callback
    map((results: string[]) => results.join(''))
  );

  function A(n) {
    let r = "A".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  function B(n) {
    let r = "B".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  function C(n) {
    let r = "C".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  function D(n) {
    let r = "D".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  // --- BELOW Part can NOT be edit ---

  runLib(A, B, C, D);
  return obs;
}
```

You can find the full code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hhct3h?devtoolsheight=60) or run below snippet

```js
// SET-UP - NOT EDIT Below code
const { Subject } = rxjs;
const { take, bufferCount, map } = rxjs.operators; // example

// simulated lib functions
function libA(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(2), 1000); } 
function libB(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(3), 3000); }
function libC(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(4), 2000); }
function libD(callback) { setTimeout( _=>callback(5), 1500); }

function runLib(cA,cB,cC,cD) {
    libA( cA ); libB( cB ); libC( cC ); libD( cD );
}

getData().subscribe(finalResult => {
  console.log(finalResult) // The result is WRONG here!
}, e=>{},_=> console.log('finished - unsubscribed'));


function getData() {
  // --- BELOW Part can be EDIT ---
  const result$ = new Subject();

  function A(n) {
    let r = "A".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  function B(n) {
    let r = "B".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  function C(n) {
    let r = "C".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  function D(n) {
    let r = "D".repeat(n);
    result$.next(r);
  }

  const obs = result$.pipe(
    bufferCount(4), // or any desired number of callback
    take(1),
    map(results=> results.join``)
  );

  // --- BELOW Part can NOT be edit ---

  runLib(A, B, C, D);
  return obs;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha256-85uCh8dPb35sH3WK435rtYUKALbcvEQFC65eg+raeuc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you - very nice answer - I edit your answer and rewrite snippet to pure JS :)

Comment: @RafiHenig what should we change to unsubscribe it in right time in this solution?

Comment: @RafiHenig actually this is not the problem because I can do unsubscribe after `let subscriber = getData().subscribe` in standard way. So the unsubscription was not the point of my question.

Comment: 1. I can unsubscribe inside subscribe (when the results are ready)
2. If I use `getData().subscribe` in other function then after It done its job, there will be no no reference to used objects inside it - and garbage collector should remove all - I think

Comment: @RafiHenig he can laso use `take` operator - to unsubscribe - I update his answer - and problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following: (I like `@Tal Ohana's` answer, but the subject in his solution will never bet unsubscribed which may result in a memory lick)

```
function getData() {

  let obs = new Subject<string>();

    function A(n: number) {
      let r = 'A'.repeat(n);
      obs.next(r);
    }

    function B(n: number) {
      let r = 'B'.repeat(n);
      obs.next(r);
    }

    function C(n: number) {
      let r = 'C'.repeat(n);
      obs.next(r);
    }

    function D(n: number) {
      let r = 'D'.repeat(n);
      obs.next(r);
    }

    runLib(A, B, C, D)

  return obs.pipe(
      scan((acc, value) => acc + value),
      take(4),
      last()
    )
}
```

Comment: can you use snippet from question and create runable example in your answer? (go to answer -> edit (at the bottom) to see full snippet code)

Comment: You say in comment in Tal Ohana answer that he have problem with unsubscribe - I ask you there about give some advice to fix it - do you know how to do it? In your answer you also never unsubscribe obs observable - so probably it is similar problem here... (?)

Comment: I use `take(4)`,

Comment: the subject will get unsubscribed after 4 emissions

Comment: `bufferCount ` is more handy than `scan` and produce less calculations (scan is executed for each value and make string concatenation in your answer- buffer only grab values and map do concatenation once) - but thank you for you answer - I'm rxjs beginer and our discussion clear me the view :)

Comment: Good luck! (My opinion is that you should never trust your observable consumers to unsubscribe, and do as best as you could from your part to limit the subscriptions life) in your case you could combine both `take` and `buffercount`)